# Is There a Service/Product/Plugin for wordpress that can send/receive data to/from a Microsoft SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a client with a Point of Sale system called Counterpoint, which runs off of a Microsoft SQL server. The client's ecommerce site is built in Wordpress with the woocommerce framework, which obviously uses a MySQL database.

I want the 2 databases to essentially share any and all information whether it originates in MySQL, or in Microsoft SQL. The 2 main pieces of data I need to track are 1: inventory management and 2: customer data. I don't know if that's enough info to get a good answer. This is my first question on this site.

Answer (score 1):

This will require server alterations.  We use FreeTDS to connect to MSSQL databases.  This isn't something that Wordpress can just automatically do for you.

So to answer your question, no, but it could be done with server alterations and custom code.

If you're interested, try following [this](http://docs.moodle.org/24/en/Installing_MSSQL_for_PHP).